# What Star Wars novels are still Canon?

Tags: star-wars, canon

With Star Wars Episode 7 being released this year, this obviously throws a lot of the novel plots out of the window, especially post Return of the Jedi.

Which EU novels are considered Canon?

Comment: tl;dr: no EU novels published prior to april of 2014.

Comment: The novelisations (and possibly the junior novelisations) That's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See @Richard's blog post.

http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2015/01/the-new-star-wars-canon-guide/

It contains the wisdom of the canon.

> (Novel) Dark Disciple by Christie Golden (not yet released)
>   (Novel) Lords of the Sith by Paul S. Kemp (not yet released)
>   (Novel) Tarkin by James Luceno
>   (Novel) A New Dawn by John Jackson Miller
>   (Novel) Servants of the Empire: Edge of the Galaxy by Jason C. Fry
>   (Novel) Ezra’s Gamble by Ryder Windham
>   (Novel) Heir to the Jedi by Kevin Hearne (not yet released)

Comment: And the [novelisations](https://twitter.com/delreystarwars/status/461579307341840384)

Comment: And possibly the Scholastic junior novelisations.